# rpart package median or geometric mean instead of mean

Tags: r, median, rpart

Is it possible to change the average estimator in a region by something different from the mean, like median or geometric mean using the `rpart` library in `R`? (or another library)

I believe my tree partitioning is highly affected by extreme values and I would like to build trees showing other estimators.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the usual tricks for right-skewed responses would be to take logs. In many applications this makes the response distribution more symmetric and then you don't need to switch from the usual mean predictions.

Another solution for changing the learning of the tree would be to use some more robust scores, e.g., ranks etc. The `ctree()` function from the `partykit` offers a nonparametric inference framework for this.

Finally, the `partykit` package also allows to compute other predictions than the means from all the terminal nodes. You can easily transform `rpart` trees to `party` trees via `as.party()`. A very simple example would be to learn an `rpart` tree for the `cars` data

```
library("rpart")
data("cars", package = "datasets")
rp <- rpart(dist ~ speed, data = cars)
```

And then transform it to `party`:

```
library("partykit")
pr <- as.party(rp)
```

The tree structure remains unchanged but you get enhanced plotting and predictions. The default plot methods yield:

[image: rpart and party tree]

Furthermore, the default predictions on both objects are the same.

```
nd <- data.frame(speed = c(10, 15, 20))
predict(rp, nd)
##        1        2        3 
## 18.20000 39.75000 65.26316 
predict(pr, nd)
##        1        2        3 
## 18.20000 39.75000 65.26316
```

However, the latter allows you to specify a `FUN`ction that should be used in each of the nodes. This must be of the form `function(y, w)` where `y` is the response and `w` are the case weights. As we haven't used any weights here, we can simply ignore that argument and do:

```
predict(pr, nd, FUN = function(y, w) mean(y))
##        1        2        3 
## 18.20000 39.75000 65.26316 
predict(pr, nd, FUN = function(y, w) median(y))
##  1  2  3 
## 18 35 64 
predict(pr, nd, FUN = function(y, w) quantile(y, 0.9))
##    1    2    3 
## 28.0 57.0 92.2
```

And so on... See the package vignettes for more details.